# React Graphql Typescript - Property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I'm trying to create a simple React Graphql app, I'm using Strapi to connect to a Mongodb.

Everything is working fine and I'm simple displaying book names with a query to get all books in the mongodb

My problem is with typescript - I'm getting a `Property does not exist on type '{}'` and I can't work out how to fix it properly.

I have a Query component

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

interface IProps{
    children(data:{}): ReactElement;
    query: DocumentNode
    id?: number
}

const Query = ({children, query, id}:IProps) => {
    const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(query, {
        variables:{id:id}
    })

    if(loading) return <p>loading</p>
    if(error) return <p>Error{JSON.stringify(error)}</p>
    return children({data})
}

export default Query
```

And a simple Query

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const GET_ALL_BOOKS = gql `
    query Books{
        books{
            name
            description
        }
    }
`
```

And then in App.tsx I'm calling the query and displaying the book names

I'm getting the typescript error here `{({data: {fonts}}) => {`

on data - `Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import Query from './utils/query'
import { GET_ALL_BOOKS } from './queries';
import {Books} from './generated/Books'
import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

interface BookProps{
  _id: string
  name: string
  description: string
}

interface IProps{
  children(data:{}): ReactElement;
  query: DocumentNode
  id?: number
}

interface Query{

}

const App:React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Books</h1>
      <Query query={GET_ALL_BOOKS}>
        {({data: {books}}) => { // typescript error here - Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
          return(
            <ul>
            {books.map((book: { name: string; }, i: number) => {
              return(
                <li>{book.name}</li>
              )
            })}
            </ul>
          )
        }}
      </Query>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm generating types from the query as well

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
// @generated
// This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.

// ====================================================
// GraphQL query operation: Books
// ====================================================

export interface Books_books {
  __typename: "Book";
  name: string | null;
  description: string | null;
}

export interface Books {
  bookds: (Books_books | null)[] | null;
}
```

How can I fix this typescript error